# Как проверить реальность даты?

Tags: java, дата, проверка

Генерирую пароль  на сервере в зависимости от даты и id
Юзеры повадились откатывать дату на предыдущую и пользовать не генеря новый пароль!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как проверить актуальность даты?

Я предполагаю что лучше в алгоритме использовать сравнение даты с какого-нибудь сервера в открытом доступе с текущей(или установленной в ручную) на смартфоне.

```
private final static String ServerDataUrl = "http=// советуемый вами сервис" 

private boolean DateCheck() throws Exception{ 
today.Date = new Date();
if ServerDataUrl = today.Date {return good;} else {return bad};
```

Comment: в тегах js в коде java

Comment: По моему это вообще кривая тема, а если у пользователя другая TimeZone, и бац у него по вашему коду уже завтра наступило. Можно конечно работать по UTC но тогда большая вероятность смены пароля в середине дня. По моему надо просто пересмотреть архитектуру системы аутентификации

Comment: нене, вся юзерня локальная. пароль через TOTP..

Comment: зачем вам будет проверять актуальность даты, если вы хотите в любом случае узнавать точную дату?

Comment: чтобы знать, что юзер не откатил дату назад

Comment: Ну если прям вообще так... То брать внешний API и смотреть. Как вариак : http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London.txt

Comment: А может генерировать пароль исходя из даты на сервере, а не у пользователя?